# delete marker in the map

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, marker

I can't understand why using .setMat(null) I can't delete the markers in my map.

The code is as following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>  <HEAD>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var geocoder;
            var map;
            var lat_;
            var lng_;
            var contentString="";
            var infowindow = null;
            var markerNodes = null;

            function initialize() {
                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.92, 12.93);
                var mapOptions = {
                  zoom: 6,
                  center: latlng,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
            }

            function searchLocations() {
                var ind_r_g = document.getElementById("indirizzoR").value;
                var civ_r_g = document.getElementById("civicoR").value;
                var citta_r_g = document.getElementById("cittaR").value;
                var paese_r_g = document.getElementById("paeseR").value;
                if(civ_r_g != 0 || civ_r_g != ""){
                var address = ind_r_g + civ_r_g + ", " +  citta_r_g + ", " + paese_r_g;
                }
                else{
                var address = ind_r_g +  ", " +  citta_r_g + ", " + paese_r_g;
                }

                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    searchLocationsNear(results[0].geometry.location);
                } else {
                    alert(address + ' not found');
                }
                });
            }

            function clearLocations() {
            if(markerNodes!=null){
                alert(markerNodes.length);
                for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
                    markers[i].setMap(null);
                }
                }
            }               


            function searchLocationsNear(center) {
                alert("beforeclearlocations");
                clearLocations();
                alert("afterclearlocations");
                var radius = document.getElementById('raggioR').value;
                var searchUrl = 'phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: contentString});

                downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
                    var xml = data.responseXML;
                    markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
                    for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {

                        var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
                        var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
                        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                            parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                            parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));
                        var image = '/img/'+ name +'.png';

                    contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                '<h3 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">' + markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name")+ '</h3>'+
                '<div id="bodyContent"><u>Indirizzo</u>: ' + markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address_indirizzo")  +'<br><u>Citta</u>: '+ markerNodes[i].getAttribute("city")
                + '<br><u>Paese</u>: ' + markerNodes[i].getAttribute("country") + '<br><u>Prezzo Benzina</u>: ' + markerNodes[i].getAttribute("prezzoB") + ' (euro/litro)</div>' + 
                '<u>Prezzo Diesel</u>: ' + markerNodes[i].getAttribute("prezzoD") +
                ' (euro/litro)</div>'+
                '</div>';       

                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            id: i,
                            map: map,
                            icon: image,
                            position: point,
                            html: contentString
                        });
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                            infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                            infowindow.open(map,this);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }   


            function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
                var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
                    new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
                    new XMLHttpRequest;

                request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (request.readyState == 4) {
                        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                        callback(request, request.status);
                    }
                };

                request.open('GET', url, true);
                request.send(null);
            }


            function doNothing() {}

            function check_form_r(){
                var check_i_r = document.getElementById("indirizzoR").value;
                var check_civ_r = document.getElementById("civicoR").value;
                var check_cit_r = document.getElementById("cittaR").value;
                var check_pa_r = document.getElementById("paeseR").value;           
                var check_ra_r = document.getElementById("raggioR").value;
                if( check_i_r == ""  || check_cit_r == ""  || check_pa_r == "" || check_ra_r== ""){
                    alert("Tutti i campi con asterisco sono obbligatori");
                }
                else{
                searchLocations();
                }
            }

    </script>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY onload="initialize();">
    <div  class="insertbox" style="center">
        <h5>CERCA I BENZINAI INTORNO A TE!</h5>
                    Indirizzo (*): <br/>
                    <input type="text" name="indirizzoR" id="indirizzoR"/> <br/>
                    Civico: <br/>
                    <input type="text" size="4" name="civicoR" id="civicoR"/> <br/>
                    Città (*): <br/>
                    <input type="text" name="cittaR" id="cittaR"/> <br/>
                    Paese (*): <br/>
                    <input type="text" name="paeseR" id="paeseR"/> <br/>
                    <label for="raggioR">Raggio di ricerca (*):</label><br/>
                    <select id="raggioR" name="raggioR">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">-- seleziona --</option>
                    <option value="2" id="raggio2">2 km</option>
                    <option value="5" id="raggio5">5 km</option>
                    <option value="10" id="raggio10">10 km</option>
                    </select><br/>
                    <input type="button" value="cerca"  onclick="check_form_r()"/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    (i campi con asterisco sono obbligatori)
    </div>
<div class="mapbox" id="map_canvas" style="width:700px; height:350px" ></div>   
</BODY>
```

The important point in the code is the function `clearLocations()` where I don't understand what I have to put inside to delete all the markers put before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
                    markers[i].setMap(null);
```

Shouldn't that be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
                    markerNodes[i].setMap(null);
```

There is no array called `markers` in your code (and in fact I'm surprised if you didn't get a JS error doing this).

However I think even this won't work for you.  markerNodes appears to be an array of items on your map.  It is better to create a blank array when you initialise the map, then push each marker to that array as you add it.

Here's an update of the relevant parts of your code, notice the new global variable `markers` and where we push each marker into that as they're created. And that's the array we use in the `clearLocations` function.

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var lat_;
var lng_;
var contentString="";
var infowindow = null;
var markerNodes = null;
var markers = [];

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.92, 12.93);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 6,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
}

function clearLocations() {
    alert(markers.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
}               

function searchLocationsNear(center) {
    alert("beforeclearlocations");
    clearLocations();
    alert("afterclearlocations");
    var radius = document.getElementById('raggioR').value;
    var searchUrl = 'phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: contentString});

    downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {

            var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
            var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));
            var image = '/img/'+ name +'.png';

        contentString = '<div id="content">'+
    '<h3 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">' + markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name")+ '</h3>'+
    '<div id="bodyContent"><u>Indirizzo</u>: ' + markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address_indirizzo")  +'<br><u>Citta</u>: '+ markerNodes[i].getAttribute("city")
    + '<br><u>Paese</u>: ' + markerNodes[i].getAttribute("country") + '<br><u>Prezzo Benzina</u>: ' + markerNodes[i].getAttribute("prezzoB") + ' (euro/litro)</div>' + 
    '<u>Prezzo Diesel</u>: ' + markerNodes[i].getAttribute("prezzoD") +
    ' (euro/litro)</div>'+
    '</div>';       

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                id: i,
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                position: point,
                html: contentString
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                infowindow.open(map,this);
            });

            // add this marker to our array
            markers.push(marker);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I already tried with `markerNodes[i].setMap(null);` but it doesn't work, as you said. `markerNodes` read from an xml file all the occurences for the markers and then put the marker respect to the values in that file. Where and how I can use a blank array?

Comment: You're also probably going to have problems with your event listener on the marker click (getting the content of the last marker for every marker that you click). You need to delegate that to an external function

Comment: No problem, feel free to [accept my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) if it works for you

Comment: You should probably ask this as a new question, it'll be easier to get it answered